# Finding an Explicit formula using Backtracking

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have just started learning Recurrence Relation and there's this topic where we have to find explicit formula using Backtracking.
There is this one question thats bugging my head a lot, ie.

$$ c_n = c_{n-1} + n \\ c_1 = 4$$

I end up getting the answer $4+(n(n+1))/2$, while the right answer is $3+(n(n+1)/2)$
Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to mse! I've edited your question to use mathjax (rather than an image) so that future people with similar questions can find this by searching for it. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Your solution does not give $c_n=4$ for $n=1$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks, I am new around here, hence I wasn't sure on how to do that.

Comment: @Oбжорoв this is literally a problem from the discrete mathematical structure by Kolmann.

Comment: @chris That may be so, but $4+1\times 2/2 =5 \neq 4$. Your are probably misquoting the problem and should have $c_n=c_{n-1}+n$ for $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what the backtracking strategy is, by I have the following solution.

By definition $c_n = c_{n-1} + n$. Let’s continue to expand: $c_n = (c_{n-2} + n-1) + n = \ldots = c_1 + 2 + \ldots + n = 3 + (1 + 2 + \ldots + n) = 3 + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$

Here I used the fact that $1 + 2 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

One can proof it this way: $n(n+1) = \underbrace{(n+1)+\cdots+(n+1)}_{n\text{ times}} = (n + 1) + ((n - 1) + 2) + ((n-2)+3)+\cdots + (3+(n-2))+(2 + (n-1))+(1 + n) = (n + (n-1) + \cdots + 2 + 1) + (1+ 2 +\cdots+(n-1)+n)=2(1+ 2 +\cdots+(n-1)+n).$

Comment: Even though the answer is correct, I am confused.
Like how do you come to the conclusion: 3 + ( 1 + 2 + ...+n ) 'cause the initial condition itself is 4 how does it become 3. :\ and why is it c1+ 2+ ...+n instead of c1+ 1 + 2 + ...+n

Comment: You can notice that sub index of $c$ is one less than the added number: $c_n = c_{n-1} + n,$ here the sub index is $n-1$, the added number is $n$. This will be true for $c_1$ which means that the added number is 2.

Comment: Other way to see this is the opposite of backtracking. One can start from the beginning: $c_1 = 4, c_2 = c_1 + 2, c_3 = c_2 + 3 = c_1 + 2 + 3 = \cdots$

Comment: This actually made more sense thanks a lot!